# How to get files from SharePoint C# Word VSTO addin?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, word, add-ins

I am trying to get **.doc** file names from SharePoint and then get the file by the name.

But I have a problem to using GetList() from [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/dn793734%28v%3doffice.15%29).

So far I have a code:

```
string url = "https://mysharepoint.com/Things";

var ctx = new ClientContext(url);
Web web = ctx.Web;

var list = web.GetList("/Shared%20Documents/Test");

var listItems = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery());

ctx.Load(listItems,
 items => items.Include(
  item => item["Created"],
  item => item.File));

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(var item in listItems) {
 Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",
  item["Created"],
  item.File.ServerRelativeUrl);
}
```

But I can't understand why I have that Error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Web' does not contain a definition for 'GetList' and no accessible extension method 'GetList' accepting a first argument of type 'Web' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MestoDljaProb   C:\Ribbon1.cs   111 Active
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void ctx_MixedAuthRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e) // function which tells to sharepoint that we need to log in with windows credentials. Without this it will tell us that we cant get in.
        {                                                                   // thats because we have sharepoint on premise 2016 with multiple(2) autents. we are using AD.
            try
            {
                //Add the header that tells SharePoint to use Windows authentication.
                e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders.Add(
                "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error setting authentication header: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private void UuendaNimekiri_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            int ConnectionTest = 0; //will try to connect once
            ddList.Items.Clear();
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://somesite/some");
            //Configure the handler that will add the header.
            ctx.ExecutingWebRequest +=
            new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(ctx_MixedAuthRequest);
            //Set the Windows credentials.
            ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            ctx.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //Get the web.
            Web w = ctx.Web;
            //Load lists with all properties. 
            List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
```